# trying to get count statistics for simple db table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to extract name, # kills, # deaths from a simple database table.

The table has

_from (killer), _to (person who died), and then a wiretap of the event.  In the case of pvp, we want to count if the person died or got a kill and add it to their total

Can this be done with a query or will I have to script something?  This don't work @ all:

```
SELECT (select COUNT( _from ) from wiretaps group by _from) as num_kills, 
       (select COUNT( _to ) from wiretaps group by _to) as num_deaths, 
        _from as name
FROM wiretaps
WHERE message LIKE  "%PvP:%"
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e5d9/1

```
| _FROM |    _TO | MESSAGE | ID |
---------------------------------
|  naez |  salty |    PvP: |  1 |
|  naez | prince |    PvP: |  2 |
| chuck |   naez |    PvP: |  3 |
```

expected output:

```
| name |    num_kills | num_deaths |
---------------------------------
|  naez   |  2 |    1 | 
|  prince |  0 |    1 | 
| chuck   |  1 |    0 | 
| salty   |  0 |    1 |
```

Comment: Try taking the group by clauses out of your subqueries.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Can you post sample data and expected results, and maybe make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: just counts total rows

Comment: You can count total rows with `select count(*) from wiretaps`.

Comment: no thats what taking out the group by clauses does. I'm trying to format it as name, #kills, #deaths.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e5d9/1

Comment: Well that certainly changes the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name, sum(num_kills) num_kills, sum(num_deaths) num_deaths
from (
    select _from name, count(*) num_kills, 0 num_deaths
    from wiretaps
    where message like '%PvP:%'
    group by _from
    union all
    select _to name, 0 num_kills, count(*) num_deaths
    from wiretaps
    where message like '%PvP:%'
    group by _to) x
group by name
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e5d9/7)

Comment: Even though I upvoted this, I think a simple union is more correct than a union all.  If buddy has the same number of kills as deaths, a union all will return both rows and the sums will give double the correct values.

Comment: @DanBracuk No, because the subquery that counts kills has 0 for deaths, and vice versa.